# A jar contains seven red and three green beans.

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, means

> Four beans are randomly withdrawn in succession with replacement, and the number of red beans, $X$, is observed. Determine $\mu$,  $\sigma_2$, and $\sigma$ for the random variable $X$.

I'm not really sure how to do this problem or where to start.

If μ = np, and n=4 and p is the probability, would it be the probability of one red marble (7/10) or all four red marbles (7/10)^4? Am i on the right track?

Comment: Are you familiar with the mean, variance of the binomial distribution? Then this will be very quick.

Comment: Not really. I suppose i can try and look it up and start from there.

Comment: Well, you don't really need it. For $k=0,1,2,3,4$ find $\Pr(X=k)$. Using these numbers, and formulas you have probably seen, you can then find the mean and the variance of $X$.

Comment: I see from the edit that you know the formula $\mu=np$. We have $n=4$ and $p=7/10$.  For $p$ is the probability of "success" (red) on any individual trial.

Comment: Ok yea so its just μ = 4(.7) = 2.8 and σ^2 = 4(.7)(.3) = 0.84 and then just square root the variance for the standard deviation, i think

Comment: That's right. So you did know the mean and variance of the binomial distribution.